# How do I get the text from a tkinter Entry widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have been trying everything and im pretty much exhausted. The problem is that there comes up an error "Can't convert 'Entry' object to str implicitly" And i doesnt find any way to make it work.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

def wcommand():
     import webbrowser
     new=2;
     url='https://'+w
     webbrowser.open(url,new=new);

root = Tk()


Label (root, text="Nettadresse:").grid(row=0)
w = Entry(root)
w.grid(row=0, column=1,)

b1 = Button(root, text='Kjør!', command=wcommand).grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.get` method to get the text from the [Entry](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) widget:

```
url='https://{}'.format(w.get())
```

Comment: No prob, you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with your code. First, you don't need those semicolons. Second, you don't want `url='https://'+w` there, you want `url='https://'+w.get()` there. The `.get()` will retrieve the string contents of that `Entry` widget. Third, instead of:

```
Label (root, text="Nettadresse:").grid(row=0)
```

you should do:

```
mylabel = Label(root, text="Nettadresse:")
mylabel.grid(row=0)
```

This will ensure that you can refer to this `Label` object later, in case you want to reconfigure it or move it or something. Fourth, you should `import webbrowser` as the second line of your code, right below `from tkinter import *`, rather than every time that function is called.